# Removing Product Review but retain the Product Rating

Tags: review, ratings

is there a way of **disabling Product Review** but **retain Product rating**?

I already disabled the Product Review in the backend but in the frontend the ratings will not be displayed.

I would like to get rid of the review but the ratings will remain by asking the user to login first before they can rate, then after login they can give a 1-5 star for the rating to the Product. Is this achievable? Any insights? solutions? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that when you disable `Mage_Review` then `Mage_Rating` also gets disabled.

You can manually remove the review form by editing the following template file:

`app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/template/review/form.phtml`

The review form is submitted to `postAction()` of class `Mage_Review_ProductController` (`app/code/core/Mage/Review/controllers/ProductController.php`).

---

In `postAction()` function, you will see this code:

`$validate = $review->validate();`

You can set `$validate` to `true`:

`$validate = true;`

Or, edit the `validate()` function in class `Mage_Review_Model_Review` (`app/code/core/Mage/Review/Model/Review.php`).

Comment: Yes I tried editing but when I tried clicking the submit, it won't proceed because of the validation.  Is this where I edit the validation? 

app/code/core/Mage/Review/controllers/ProductController.php

Comment: Yes, you have to edit the validation over there. You may rewrite `Mage_Review_ProductController` with your custom module or just make a local copy at `app/code/local/Mage/Review/controllers/ProductController.php` and edit in the local copy.

Comment: Hi Mukesh, I tried but I can't pin down which one to edit for the validation. Can you guide me exactly which one? If it's ok?

Comment: And also where do I get to edit the text "Be the first to Review this product"?

Comment: @KiDCajes : I have update the answer. Please check.

Comment: I tried the first method didn't work.

Comment: It's only showing me "Unable to post review" :-(

Comment: Will you be able to help me?